# Expected an identifier and instead saw 'import' (a reserved word) jshint

Tags: vue.js, jshint

I am getting following warning in vscode:

> Expected an identifier and instead saw 'import' (a reserved word). (W024)jshint(W024)

My code is as following:

```js
import {
    createRouter,
    createWebHistory
} from "@ionic/vue-router";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: () => import("../views/Home.vue")
    },
    {
        path: "/manufacturers",
        name: "Manufacturers",
        component: () => import("../views/Manufacturers.vue") // getting error in this import
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Guess you already tried `reload window`?

Answer (score 1):

JSHint can be configured to enable ES2015 (ES6) language features, which include the `import` keyword for modules, by setting [`esversion`](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion):

```js
// .jshintrc
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

or

```json
// package.json
{
  "jshintConfig": {
    "esversion": 6
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using esversion 9 and still getting this error

Comment: What version of JSHint are you using? Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: I am using jshint version v2.12.0